# Changing binary digits with different numbers of simultaneous operations

Tags: binary, bit-manipulation

I’m a maths teacher and have been given the following task for pupils to do.
3 pupils are sitting down.  Can all be changed from sitting to standing?  The only allowed move is for 2 people to change state from sitting to standing simultaneously (or vice versa).  It turns out it is not possible and in fact the only configurations that can be achieved are 0 standing and 2 standing.
Now if there are 4 people sitting with the same allowed move, clearly all can be changed to standing.  Again 1 and 3 people standing is not possible.
If the definition of a move is changed to 3 people changing from sitting to standing simultaneously (or vice versa).   Then for 4 people - 1,2,3, and 4 people standing can be achieved.  The pattern can then be investigated for different moves and numbers of people.
Since this is all about binary changes it seems to me that there must be some practical implication for this bit of logic from the world of computer science.  If there is, perhaps someone could enlighten me and I can add this as an extra hook to the lesson.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Although this question is interesting, it is probably not the right place to ask it because it is not really a "programming question".

Comment: Actually, it is a nice little puzzle. I believe that it is not possible exactly if the number of sim-changes is even and the number of students is odd (because the total number of standing students is always even then), while it is possible in any other case because you can construct a combined move that only changes a few (2 or 1, depending on the case) student's states. Actually, I am not aware of any computer science implications, especially because in CS you usually consider numbers of bits which are even (8, 16, 32, ...) so that the impossible cases of the problem do not occur.

Comment: The operation preserves parity, so it splits the "reachability graph" into an even and an odd part that can't reach each other. Roughly the same effect occurs in N-puzzles but it's a bit more complicated.

Comment: This could be good here: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ In CS I would say it would be a good example of getting your code into an infinite loop or recursion and having the code know when it has hit an improbable/impossible iterative problem. *shrug*